# SQL Server data lost by changing stored procedure that puts data in it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a stored procedure that stores data in a table. Yesterday, I changed one var type from `decimal(15,0)` to `varchar(10)` in my stored procedure.

Today I see that my table has new rows but previous data has gone.

Is my data lost? Is this data loss because of that change? If I don't have a backup how can I bring back the data?

Comment: Well, `decimal(15)` can hold numbers up to 15 digits before the comma - that cannot be stored in a `varchar(10)` obviously..... so this *might* break when you call this stored procedure. But changing a stored procedure's parameters (that's what you mean, right?) shouldn't affect the tables at all.

Comment: yes thats is the case. But i dont know why that happened.

Comment: Changing a stored procedures variables data type will not affect existing data unless it introduces a bug and you execute it. Perhaps the stored procedure deletes existing data based on a comparison to this variable, and this comparison has now incorrectly resulted in data being deleted. If you don't have a backup your only option is to buy a tool that trawls through the transaction log, assuming the changes are still in the transaction log. Lesson learnt: always make backups and consider using a development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Changing parameter type in a procedure definitely didn't cause the data loss. SQL Server won't delete the data unless an explicit delete command was issued (or drop or truncate or similar).

If the database is in full recovery model you can still take a backup and restore to another server with `stopat` option.